# Memory leak turnjs

Tags: jquery, memory-leaks, turnjs, ebook-reader

I have problem with book reader
here is my code:

[**Code**](http://jsfiddle.net/3WRR8/1/)

I using `turnjs v3` library and i have problem with memory leak, if you reading next and next page, memory RAM is not cleared but is gaining more and more.

In console i see that `DOM` is removed, but I think of is not deleted from the memory, I know that the images have a larger size than is usual but I think this is not the main problem.

If you are experiencing something similar and later mate solution I would be grateful if you could help me

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Spontaneously I would say, it's because you add all the images to the document at once, and while the browser (in my case Chrome) doesn't actually load them until the page is displayed, there is no reason for it to unload them.

You should try writing it, so that you only add the images to the DOM when you display them, and remove them when not.

Comment: Which part of code you mean? i only store data in array but i show only page wich ich need, in console "Cislo stranky" mean " Number of page which is rendering